# how to prgramatically trigger mouse click in c .net

Tags: c++, .net, triggers, mouseclick-event

I am new to c++.net. I want to programatically trigger mouse click event of webBrowser, the reason is that I use the webBrowser control to display the .ppt file and I want it to automatically jump to the second page without clicking the mouse. Is there any way to trigger the mouse click event programatically?

thanks.

Comment: The [`mouse_event` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx) is the one you need, although that has been replaced by [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) so Google both for guidance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to give a bit more information. Include what you have tried already and then ask `What is wrong with my solution?` rather than `What is the solution?`